# asp.net core (3+) shared context on CreateScope()

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

When I try to run a background task, I always create a new scope inside that task. With the update to 3+, it seems that within the new create scope, there is a reference to the original request. The following code would break on the Debugger.Break() statement:

```
public class TestController : Controller
{
    public readonly IServiceScopeFactory ServiceScopeFactory;

    public TestController(
        IServiceScopeFactory serviceScopeFactory)
    {
        this.ServiceScopeFactory = serviceScopeFactory;
    }

    // GET
    public IActionResult Index()
    {
        Task.Run(() =>
        {
            using (var scope = ServiceScopeFactory.CreateScope())
            {
                var actionContextAccessor = scope.ServiceProvider.GetService<IActionContextAccessor>();
                var actionContext = actionContextAccessor.ActionContext;

                if (actionContext.ActionDescriptor != null)
                    Debugger.Break();
            }
        });

        return Content("Test");
    }
}
```

The startup looks like this:

```
public class Startup
{
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddControllers();
        services.AddSingleton<IActionContextAccessor, ActionContextAccessor>();
    }

    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
    {
        if (env.IsDevelopment())
        {
            app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
        }

        app.UseRouting();
        app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
        {
            endpoints.MapControllers();
            endpoints.MapControllerRoute(
                name: "default",
                pattern: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
        });
    }
}
```

The problem is that httpContext is shared with the new create scope. When one of the scopes is being disposed of, it affects the other scope. For example with IUrlHelper, which results in an "IFeatureCollection has been disposed of".

For test sake, I added a test if the httpContext would be the same. And it seems it is!

```
public IActionResult Index()
{
    // Just for testing
    var originalContext = this.HttpContext;

    Task.Run(() =>
    {
        using (var scope = ServiceScopeFactory.CreateScope())
        {
            // Make sure the original request was disposed
            Thread.Sleep(1000);

            var actionContextAccessor = scope.ServiceProvider.GetService<IActionContextAccessor>();
            var actionContext = actionContextAccessor.ActionContext;

            if (originalContext == actionContext.HttpContext)
                Debugger.Break();
        }
    });

    return Content("Test");
}
```

For me, this seems like odd behaviour, cause I would except the new scope not to have the same httpContext. It should be a NEW scope. Should the scope be created in another way?

### Found solution

In my production code I use a transient ActionContext scope, which attempt to detect if it's dealing with a request, or a background scope as followed:

```
services.AddSingleton<IActionContextAccessor, ActionContextAccessor>()
    .AddTransient<ActionContext>((s) => {
        var actionContextAccessor = serviceProvider.GetRequiredService<IActionContextAccessor>();
        var actionContext = actionContextAccessor?.ActionContext;

        // Create custom actioncontext
        if (actionContext == null) {
             // create a manual actionContext
        }


        return actionContext;
    });
```

This doesn't seem to work anymore. The solution seems to be too validate if the httpContext exist through the IHttpContextAccessor:

```
services.AddSingleton<IActionContextAccessor, ActionContextAccessor>()
    .AddTransient<ActionContext>((s) => {
        var currentContextAccess = serviceProvider.GetService<IHttpContextAccessor>();
        if (currentContextAccess.HttpContext == null) {
             // create a manual actionContext
             ...

             return actionContext;
        }

        var actionContextAccessor = serviceProvider.GetRequiredService<IActionContextAccessor>();
        return actionContextAccessor.ActionContext;
    });
```

Comment: Why odd? Context accessor is a singleton (same as IHttpContextAccessor is), so its normal to return the same instance even inside a scope. ALso what are you trying to achieve? Since you are not awaiting, the `Task.Run`, your request will finish before the task is finished, so what do you want to access thin? HttpContext is only valid for the duration of the request and since you dont await it, request ends early

Comment: Also its undefined behavior, see David's Guidelines [Do not access the HttpContext from multiple threads in parallel. It is not thread safe.](https://github.com/davidfowl/AspNetCoreDiagnosticScenarios/blob/master/AspNetCoreGuidance.md#do-not-access-the-httpcontext-from-multiple-threads-in-parallel-it-is-not-thread-safe) and [Do not use the HttpContext after the request is complete](https://github.com/davidfowl/AspNetCoreDiagnosticScenarios/blob/master/AspNetCoreGuidance.md#do-not-use-the-httpcontext-after-the-request-is-complete)

Comment: My expectation would be, that actionContext.HttpContext is null. As it was on asp.net core 2.2

Comment: Again, its **undefined** behavior. Do. not. rely. on. undefined. behavior. Thats why there are no guarantees it will stay same inbetween the versions. Just don't use undefined behaviors (see linked guidelines). Undefined behavior means if you use it **ANYTHING** can happen. You could get null, same context (before disposal) or a context from a different thread. It's **not defined**.

Comment: This is just for demonstration. My question is, why is there a (the same) context when I create a new scope within another thread (the task in this case).

Comment: Singletons will always be shared with the scope. Post a concrete example, with a real DI setup then

Comment: Ok, actionContextAccessor.ActionContext seems to be implemented as an AsyncLocal<T> property, which returns a thread depending value. So IActionContextAccessor is a singleton, but the value of ActionContext is not.

In my production code, a AddTransient<ActionContext>(...) was used to get the ActionContext, which used the actionContextAccessor.ActionContext to detect if it was a request or something that runs in the background. If it had not HttpContext, one was created to be used in for the ActionContext. This seems to have changed.

Comment: `AddTransient<ActionContext>(...)` make no sense. `ActionContext` is never resolved via DI, neither is `HttpContext` (or rather `DefaultHttpContext` since `HttpContext` was a abstract class last time I looked). Neither `HttpContext` nor `ActionContext` is created by the IoC/DI container. Its `new`d up somewhere in the request pipeline, thats why you can't inject `HttpContext` or `ActionContext` and why you need the `XxxAccessor` to do that (why by default aren't registered for performance penalty that comes with it and `AsyncLocal<T>` - so its opt-in)

Comment: I came across the same issue, understanding the `HttpContext` is not available in an `IHostedService` even when creating a scope. My solution was to create another `BackgroundWebHost` and inject it into the `IHostedService`like descriped here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59849482/use-razorviews-in-an-aspnetcore-3-ihostedservice

Comment: The ActionContext is required for rendering razor views in the background

Comment: > rendering razor views in the background
exactly, that's how I did it

Comment: Even with the updated code and solutions you are asking for trouble and you are depending on undefined behavior. Why don't create a factory that creates an instance of the ActionContext that has the desired values required for the rendering?

Comment: Because the code is shared between background, foreground and testing, and has no context of the situation its in. IHttpContextAccessor seems to be the correct way to go. Thanks for your time and suggestions

Answer (score 1):

> For me, this seems like odd behaviour, cause I would except the scope not to be. Should the scope be created in another way?

Why odd? `IActionContextAccessor` is a singleton (same as `IHttpContextAccessor` is), so its normal to return the same instance even inside a newly created scope.

Since you are not awaiting, the `Task.Run`, your request will **finish before the task is finished**. How do you want to access the HttpContext after the request is done? It's only valid during the request. You have to get all the required data prior to spinning up the new Task and pass the values you need to the background task.

`HttpContext` is only valid for the duration of the request and since you dont await it, request ends early.

And what your code does is undefined behavior, see David's Guidelines

- [Do not access the HttpContext from multiple threads in parallel. It is not thread safe.](https://github.com/davidfowl/AspNetCoreDiagnosticScenarios/blob/master/AspNetCoreGuidance.md#do-not-access-the-httpcontext-from-multiple-threads-in-parallel-it-is-not-thread-safe)
- [Do not use the HttpContext after the request is complete](https://github.com/davidfowl/AspNetCoreDiagnosticScenarios/blob/master/AspNetCoreGuidance.md#do-not-use-the-httpcontext-after-the-request-is-complete)

Comment: The point is that I don't want to access the HttpContext. I want a 'clean' scope to handle background tasks. The code is just an example to show the behaviour. And true, its singleton (it has to be), but in every request, the IActionContextAccessor does have an own context, without it being added with AddScope